# Trying to register an amazon s3 presigned url and getting an error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The question it self explanatory, when trying to create a presigned url I get the following error:

```
Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1001 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))
```

I have used the code from here exactly https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html

My code is below:

```
    $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
        'version' => '2006-03-01',
    ]);

    $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => 'my-bucket-name',
        'Key'    => 'AKIAJNCZ5***********'
    ]);

    $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

    // Get the actual presigned-url
    $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();


    print_r($presignedUrl);
```

Any reason why this is happening?

EDIT::

Ok so this fixed my problem, but it wasnt not actually even in the docs:

```
 $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
        'version' => '2006-03-01',
        'credentials' => ['key' => 'AKIAJNCZ5MY*******8','secret'=>'NgeFc+2/Q2cUAmL/+lP2gp***********8']
    ]);
```

Adding the credentials assoc array :)

However I am now unsure how to use this presigned url to download one of my files aha, so if anyone knows and doesnt mind putting me in the right direction :)

Comment: I assume you've tried `$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client` instead of `$s3Client = new S3Client`? The only reason I ask is you say you used the code from that link exactly, except the example code you have is missing the `Aws\S3\ ` part.

Comment: im using laravel, and i import the class at the top "use Aws\S3\S3Client", thats why i only do = new S3Client

Comment: What is your AWS SDk Version?

Comment: Gotcha. And if it didn't know what the class was, you'd be getting a completely different error anyway.

Comment: the version is 3.18^

Comment: Can you change 'version' => '2006-03-01' to 'version' => 'latest' and see if you still get the error?

Comment: Also many times the above error happens when your SDK does not have the correct credentials for the AWS. Jut test if you are able to list the content of the bucket through your SDK.

Comment: I ave updated question, now its working. But im unsure how to download a file with htis presigned url

Comment: Where do you want to download the file to?

Comment: Just a normal download. So it goes to the url and then downloads through the browser

Comment: What happens when you paste the generated Presigned URL into your browser? Check this documentation http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-generate-url-for-amazon-s3-files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Key' in the `getCommand` array is the name/path to the file you want to generate  a pre-signed URL for, not your AWS key :)

```
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket-name',
    'Key'    => 'path/to/file.txt', // or just file.txt if it's in the root of the bucket
]);
```